# How to Perform SSH Log Poisoning for RCE with LFI Using PHP System Call in Username (terminal)

Tags: security, logging, ssh

**Background**:
I am currently working on passing a certification that involves a lab where I need to execute Remote Code Execution (RCE) via Local File Inclusion (LFI) and SSH Log Poisoning. The objective is to inject PHP code into the SSH logs by using a malicious username, which can then be executed through an LFI vulnerability on the target server.

**Issue**:
I attempted to perform SSH Log Poisoning by injecting PHP code into the username part of the SSH command. The command I used is as follows:

```
ssh '<?php system($_GET['c']); ?>'@192.168.1.129
```

However, when I run this command, I encounter the following error:

```
remote username contains invalid characters
```

This error suggests that the SSH client is rejecting the username due to the presence of special characters, which are part of the PHP code I'm trying to inject.

**What I've Tried:**

- Escaping the single quotes in the PHP code, but it didn't resolve the issue.
- Searching for alternative ways to encode or disguise the PHP code within the username, but I haven't found a method that bypasses the validation yet.

**Question**:
How can I successfully inject PHP code into the username for SSH Log Poisoning without triggering the "invalid characters" error? Is there a specific encoding or bypass technique that works for this scenario?

Comment: A python, perl, java, etc. ssh client library might be more willing to send a dodgy username to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This vulnerability is now patched from upstream `ssh`.

Your ressource https://www.hackingarticles.in/rce-with-lfi-and-ssh-log-poisoning/ is from 2017:
7 years old!

Check the function `valid_ruser()` in this patch: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/7ef3787c84b6b524501211b11a26c742f829af1a

---

To test/install impacted Ubuntu 16.04: https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

or from git repository:

```
git checkout <sha1>
# compiling ssh from here
```

where `sha1` is a commit before `7ef3787c84b6b524501211b11a26c742f829af1a`

Comment: I tried that and all quote-related combinations, but nothing worked. Also, I'm calling this SSH command directly from a command line interface (CLI), not a PHP script, as all I need is to get the connection attempt in the /var/log/auth.log file to gain an access point [Read this article to better understand my goal](https://www.hackingarticles.in/rce-with-lfi-and-ssh-log-poisoning/)

Comment: I understand that the vulnerability has been patched, but there are still individuals exploiting it. I am curious about how to bypass the restriction that was not present during the time of the vulnerability.

Comment: You can install a old Linux box for this. It's very easy. Edited my post

Comment: I considered that option, but I would prefer a way to bypass it.

Comment: So why not compiling `ssh` with a `git checkout <sha1>` where `sha1` is a commit before `7ef3787c84b6b524501211b11a26c742f829af1a`? This is very simple. Are you a complete beginner?